# Parsing unicode csv with unicodecsv module

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Parsing csv output of console command with Python 2.7. Standart `csv` module did not work properly, so I`ve found `unicodecsv` module. 
The iteration outputs strange results (empty lists or strings separated to chars), but I expect to see list with values for each row:

```
import unicodecsv
csv_parsed = unicodecsv.reader(utf8_csv_string, delimiter=',')

for row in csv_parsed:
    print row

>[u'0']
>[]
>[u'']
>[u'', u'']
>[u'', u'']
>[u'', u'']
>[u'19102.00']
>[u'', u'']
>[u'2']
>[u'1']
>[u'2']
>[u'', u'']
>[u'0']
>[]
```

Where is the mistake?

**PS:** Using Python 3 is not an option.

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: `"field1","field2","field3","field4","field5",\n`  100% valid. Parsing it with PHP works properly.

Comment: I think the reader function expects a file handle and not a string. You could use StringIO to wrapt the string

Comment: @Niemerds, with StringIO it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [`unicodecsv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1) expects a bytestream. So

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = unicodecsv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
```

should work. Actually if you look at the [tests on github](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv/blob/4563e33ce322f5e2dea41e76cb33dc0e008ad341/unicodecsv/test.py#L623-L637) you can see that is how the author of the library uses it.